# Translation of "If so"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

How do you say "if so" in German?

> Do you have some time? If so, I would like to speak with you.

Would you say "wenn ja"?

> Haben Sie etwas Zeit? Wenn ja, ich möchte mit Ihnen sprechen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost perfect.
Yes I would use *"Wenn ja,"* , but if you use this you need to invert the structure of the following sentence, due to the implied *"dann"*:

> Wenn ja, [dann] möchte ich mit Ihnen sprechen.

Alternatively you could also say: *"Falls ja"*, *"In dem Falle"*
a little discurteous: *"Dann"* because this implies you expect the one you asked to have time

As suggested by @Toscho and @Dustin:

- *"In diesem Fall,"*
- *"Falls / Wenn dem so ist,"*

And as a more polite Alternative:

> Falls sie Zeit haben, [dann] möchte ich mit Ihnen [über Thema xy] sprechen.

Comment: Further alternatives: `In diesem Fall …`, `Falls/Wenn dem so ist, …`.

Comment: To add on to the "Falls" construction, I'd like to suggest: Falls Sie Zeit haben, dann möchte ich mit Ihnen sprechen.